# Getting the list of all tags in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to get the the list of all available tags in Unity. Is there any simple way to achieve this?

Comment: UnityEditorInternal.InternalEditorUtility.tags

Comment: Thanks. Works like a charm.

Comment: But that's undocumented APIs that are not officially supported and might be deleted at some point. So, don't really rely on them working 4ever :)

Comment: write it as an answer, so we can close the question :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
UnityEditorInternal.InternalEditorUtility.tags
```

But APIs under UnityEditorInternal are not officially supported and might be deleted at some point. So, don't really rely on them working forever